# Cannot parse project property android.useAndroidX='true ' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'

Tags: android

Build file 'E:\Android\orMusic\app\build.gradle' line: 1

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Cannot parse project property android.useAndroidX='true ' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
> --scan to get full insights.

- ```
     Exception is:
     org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
         at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
         at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
         at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
         at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
         at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
         at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
         at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
         at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
         at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
         at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
         at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
         at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
         at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
         at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:723)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:150)
         at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
         at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:69)
         at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
         at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
         at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
         at 
         ... 176 more
  ```

  ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— build.gradle:

  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 31
  buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
  defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.orhome.ormusic"
  minSdkVersion 16
  targetSdkVersion 31
  multiDexEnabled true
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
  testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  ```
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
     compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }
     kotlinOptions {
         jvmTarget = '1.8'
     }
     buildFeatures {
         viewBinding true
     }
  ```

  }

  dependencies {

  ```
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
     implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
     implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
     implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'


     def room_version = "1.1.1"
     implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
     annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version" // use kapt for Kotlin
     // optional - RxJava support for Room
     implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"
     // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
     implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:guava:$room_version"
     // Test helpers
     testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"

     implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
     implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
     implementation project(':haicycle')
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around True, its expecting a boolean rather than a String

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Now solved, weird phenomenon
In gradle.properties, no matter whether there is android.useAndroidX=true, or delete android.useAndroidX=true, this error occurs. Later, after I set android.useAndroidX=false, android started to download some plug-ins, and it was fine